# Encountered "TypeError: integer argument expected, got float" while trying to plot a simple column chart

Tags: python, python-2.7, graph, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to plot a simple column chart using [xlsxwriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/). The following is the script I wrote for the same:

```
import xlsxwriter

cmui = [456.0,424.08,114.0,22.8,22.8]
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('first.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type':'column'})
dec = workbook.add_format({'num_format':'#0.000000'})
bold = workbook.add_format()
bgc = workbook.add_format({'bold':'True'})
bgc.set_pattern(1)
bgc.set_bg_color("#DD8000")
chart.add_series({'values':cmui})
chart.set_title({'name':'Example'})
chart.set_y_axis({'name':'A'})
chart.set_x_axis({'name':'B'})
worksheet.insert_chart('A10',chart)
workbook.close()
```

When I try and execute the above, I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

Which is understandably because I'm passing a list with floating type values inside. But does this mean I cannot plot floating point values at all or is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `chart.add_series()` `values` property doesn't take a list of data values like that you should write the data to the worksheet and reference it. Like this:

```
worksheet.write_column('A1', cmui)
chart.add_series({'values': 'Sheet1!A1:A5'})
```

The list parameter for `values` is used specify a the range dimensions so that you don't have to programmatically generate an Excel range like `Sheet1!A1:A5`:

```
chart.add_series({'values': ['Sheet1', 0, 0, 4, 0]})
```

Comment: That solved it! I happened to notice that in the docs. I was trying to write the same to the worksheet and then plot the graph. So, I thought why not directly write the list. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting it wrong. According to the docs:

```
chart.add_series({
    'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5',
    'values':     '=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$5',
    'line':       {'color': 'red'},
})

# Or using a list of values instead of category/value formulas:
#     [sheetname, first_row, first_col, last_row, last_col]
chart.add_series({
    'categories': ['Sheet1', 0, 0, 4, 0],
    'values':     ['Sheet1', 0, 1, 4, 1],
    'line':       {'color': 'red'},
})
```

The `add_series()` function accepts the coordinates of spreadsheet cells, not the exact values, so you need to insert your values into the spreadsheet and then only specify thier coordinates in `values`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `set_num_format('0.00')`

See examples in the link below:

http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/format.html